# How to use static functions to call UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum() with completion handler?

Tags: ios, swift

I am able to call `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` and handle the completion without problem:

```
class A {
    func saveNow() {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(someImage, self, "saveImage:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)
    }

    func saveImage(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo:UnsafePointer<Void>) {
        // handle completion
    }
}
```

However, if I want to make `saveNow()` a static function, I am not able to set the `completionTarget` & `completionSelector` correctly so that I can handle the completion:

```
class B {
    static func saveNow() {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(someImage, /* how to set here */)
    }

    static func saveImage completionSelector(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo:UnsafePointer<Void>) {
    }
}
```

How to modify class B if I want to use static functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you'd need to do is to set the target to `YourClassName.self`.

I.e.,

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(someImage, YourClassName.self, "saveImage:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)
```

By the way, your function name is not correct:

```
//Note the space between saveImage and completionSelector
static func saveImage completionSelector(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo:UnsafePointer<Void>)
```

I think it should be:

```
static func saveImageWithCompletionSelector(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo:UnsafePointer<Void>)
```

Thus, we may need to make a corresponding change:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(someImage, YourClassName.self, "saveImageWithCompletionSelector:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)
```

I just ran a quick test with the aforementioned change and suggestion; there should be a pop-up requesting for authorization for accessing photo album.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry about the function name. It was my mistake when code copy/paste. And I did tried with `someClassName.self` but still had the error that the app couldn't find the selector method. I finally found the solution is that `class B` has to inherit `NSObject`, then the error goes away.

Comment: But I actually don't understand why I need to inherit `NSObject` in order for it to work. If someone can give further comments, it will be helpful. Thanks.